# Button in Node.js project works properly after two clicks not one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session, ejs

I'm making a simple project with node.js, express, mongodb, express session etc. It is a travel type site and a user in the database has a username, password and a list of destinations he wants to go to. Each destination page has a button to add that destination to the list and there is also a page which shows the current user's list. The proper functionality is that on the first button press the destination should be added to the users list in the database and the ejs view for the list page should be updated and on the second button press an alert should come up saying that the current destination is already on the user's list. However, seemingly randomly the button sometimes only works properly after two button presses and the alert and ejs view update of the list page occur on the third button press. Here are some code snippets:

This is my get request for the list page where I pass the current session user's want to go list as a parameter:

```
function isAuthenticated (req, res, next) {
      if (req.session.user) next()
      else res.redirect('/');
    }

app.get('/wanttogo',isAuthenticated,function(req,res){
  res.render('wanttogo',{dests:req.session.user.wantgo})
});
```

I update this list both in the session and in my database in each page's post request. This is an example for one of the pages:

```
app.post('/inca',function(req,res){
    if((req.session.user.wantgo.length === 0) || !(req.session.user.wantgo.includes("Inca Trail to Machu Picchu"))){
      req.session.user.wantgo.push("Inca Trail to Machu Picchu");
      req.session.save();

      db.collection("myCollection").updateOne({username:req.session.user.username},{$set:{wantgo:req.session.user.wantgo}});

      db.collection("myCollection").findOne({username: req.session.user.username},(err,result)=>{
        req.session.user.wantgo = result.wantgo;
        req.session.user=result;
        req.session.save();
      });
    }
    else{
      alert('This destination is already on your Want-To-Go List');
    }
    res.redirect('/inca');
```

and this is the part of the ejs view of the list page where I loop over the user's list and print it using the parameter I passed earlier:

```
<div>
        
        <% for(var i=0; i < dests.length; i++) { %>
            
              <h1><%= dests[i] %></h1>
            
         <% } %>
        
    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the fact "updateOne" and "findOne" are async functions and thus the database is not updated before you do the second button press.

Since this depends on time when the async operation is completed it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

Try using async await like this

```
app.post('/inca',async function(req,res){
    if((req.session.user.wantgo.length === 0) || !(req.session.user.wantgo.includes("Inca Trail to Machu Picchu"))){
      req.session.user.wantgo.push("Inca Trail to Machu Picchu");
      req.session.save();

      await db.collection("myCollection").updateOne({username:req.session.user.username},{$set:{wantgo:req.session.user.wantgo}});

      await db.collection("myCollection").findOne({username: req.session.user.username},(err,result)=>{
        req.session.user.wantgo = result.wantgo;
        req.session.user=result;
        req.session.save();
      });
    }
    else{
      alert('This destination is already on your Want-To-Go List');
    }
    res.redirect('/inca');
```